# Combine the bar graph and line graph

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart, linegraph

I'm trying to draw a graph as following :

[image]

I tried many libraries like **[`afreechart`](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/)**, **[`charts4j`](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)**, **[`aiChart`](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx)** and many more. I want to this type of graph,

Is it possible? Which library is useful for that? or any other solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AChartEngine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) library supports combined charts also..

You can [download source](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/?wpdmact=process&did=MTUzLmhvdGxpbms=) from here which fits your requirememnt.

For more reference [refer here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-combined-chart-using-achartengine-library/)

Comment: Thanks CRUSADER.. But line graphs point should be center of bar graph and from the all points it becomes line graph.

Comment: It will be center of bar graph, hmm,... I think you got confused in ref link provide, In there line corresponds to income and bar corresponds to expense, so you see the difference, but in your case both values are same so you get the desired graph you wanted.